# Struts2 file upload - No mapping found for dependency

Tags: file-upload, struts2, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm using Struts 2.3.20.1 with Commons File Upload 1.3.1 and Commons IO 2.4 to upload a (CSV) file. When i try to do uploading, there is this error in server log:

> ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-24) UT005023: Exception
>   handling request to /private/createDatasetFromCSV:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException:
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException:
>   No mapping found for dependency [type=java.lang.String,
>   name='struts.multipart.bufferSize'] in public void
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaStreamMultiPartRequest.setBufferSize(java.lang.String).

I've followed the official guidelines [here](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/file-upload.html), creating an `Action` class, using the JSP form tags and so on. 
In `struts.xml`, for file upload section, I have:

```
 <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize"     value="209715200" /> 
 <constant name="struts.multipart.parser"        value="jakarta-stream" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Struts should be updated due to [WW-4466](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4466).

> With WW-3025 there was a new config constant introduced: struts.multipart.bufferSize
>
> Currently it is set as required and hence applications must specify it. The default value is always overridden.
>
> -> should be required = false
>
> Fix Version/s:  2.3.24